# VueJS Supense only works whenI land on the Async component

Tags: vue.js, asynchronous, vuejs3, vue-router, vue-suspense

I read this part of documentation: https://vuejs.org/guide/built-ins/suspense.html#combining-with-other-components

I have in my menu 2 links: "Home" and "Tools". If I land on my root page, that is to say the "Home" route, then I go to the "Tools" route, the "Loading..." message doesn't show. I have to wait 2 seconds, though, meaning the async component waits to be loaded to be displayed.
If I go to the "Tools" route directly, I see the message. I don't understand what I did wrong because I want the "Loading..." message to show when I load this async component, even if I come from another route.

In my `App.vue` I have this:

```
<script setup>
import Connexion from '@/components/Connexion.vue'
import { ref } from 'vue'

const drawer = ref(null);
</script>

<template>

  <v-app>
    <v-navigation-drawer
      expand-on-hover
      rail>

      <Suspense>
        <Connexion />
        <template #fallback>
          Chargement...
        </template>
      </Suspense>

      <v-divider></v-divider>

      <v-list density="compact" nav>
        <v-list-item prepend-icon="mdi-home" title="Home" value="home" @click="$router.push('/')"></v-list-item>
        <v-list-item prepend-icon="mdi-account-multiple" title="Tools" value="tools" @click="$router.push('/tools')"></v-list-item>
      </v-list>
    </v-navigation-drawer>

    <v-app-bar>
      <v-toolbar-title>My app</v-toolbar-title>
    </v-app-bar>

    <v-main fluid fill-width>
      XXX
      <v-container
        fluid
        >
      <router-view v-slot="{ Component }">
        <template v-if="Component">
          <Transition mode="out-in">
            <keep-alive>
              <Suspense>
                <component :is="Component" />
                <template #fallback>
                  Loading...
                </template>
              </Suspense>
            </keep-alive>
          </Transition>
        </template>
      </router-view>
      </v-container>
    </v-main>
  </v-app>
</template>

<style>
/* we will explain what these classes do next! */
.v-enter-active,
.v-leave-active {
  transition: opacity 0.2s ease;
}

.v-enter-from,
.v-leave-to {
  opacity: 0;
}
</style>
```

And here is the `Tools.vue` component:

```
<script>
import { defineComponent } from "vue";
export default defineComponent({
  async setup() {
    const apiUrl = import.meta.env.VITE_APP_API_URL;
    console.log("loading...")
    const demandes = await fetch(`${apiUrl}/tools`)
      .then((r) => r.json())
      .catch((e) => {
        console.log(e);
        return [];
      });
    await new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, 2000));
    console.log("LOADED!")

    return {
      demandes,
    }
  }
})
</script>
<template>
  <div>
    <h1>Tools</h1>
    <ul>
      <li
        v-for="tool in tools"
        :key="`tool-${tool.id}`"
        >
        {{ tool }}
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</template>
```

If it has any interest, here is my `router` file:

```
import { createRouter, createWebHistory } from 'vue-router';
import { nextTick } from 'vue';

const routes = [
{
  path: '/',
  name: 'Home',
  component: () => import('@/views/Home.vue'),
  meta: {
    title: 'Home',
  },
},
{
  path: '/tools',
  name: 'Tools',
  component: () => import('@/views/Tools.vue'),
  meta: {
    title: 'Tools',
  },
},
];

const router = createRouter({
  base: import.meta.env.VITE_APP_PUBLICPATH,
  history: createWebHistory(import.meta.env.VITE_APP_BASE_URL),
  routes,
});

const DEFAULT_TITLE = import.meta.env.VITE_APP_TITLE;
router.afterEach((to) => {
  nextTick(() => {
    document.title = to.meta.title ? `${DEFAULT_TITLE} - ${to.meta.title}` : DEFAULT_TITLE;
  });
});

export default router;
```

And the `Home.vue`:

```
<script setup>
</script>

<template>
  <h1>Home</h1>
</template>

<style scoped>
</style>
```

Comment: Maybe it is caused by the `Transition` component. Try removing it to see if it is the problem. Anyway, a live demo on stackblitz.com would make us easier to debug

Comment: @djcaesar9114 Same problem, did you find a solution?

Comment: More or less.. I ended up wrapping my component in a wrapper component.
`Tools.vue` loads the different components (`ToolsList`, `ToolDetail`, etc.).
I'm not happy with that, because it doesn't feel natural.